# How do you convert javascript 'var options' to css (for Google Charts)?

Tags: javascript, css, google-visualization

Looking at the documentation for [google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_charts), it appears like the var options greatly resembles css:

```
var options = {
  width: 400,
  height: 240,
  title: 'Toppings I Like On My Pizza',
  colors: ['#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6']
};

chart.draw(data, options);
```

As such, how do you convert the above code into a file: chart.css?

edited to add: I have a much larger var options for a line graph and the reason I am asking is because I would like to organize my code more with separate files.

Comment: That's not CSS at all. What exactly is your goal? The plugin needs those values to be provided to it during initialisation so that it can calculate the size of the chart to be displayed, and the associated UI items (legends, labels etc). I don't see a workable way to replace that with CSS, whilst using the same Google Chart library.

Comment: it's not? Apologies I'm still a noob programmer. My goal was to have a separate .css file to reduce clutter and more cleanly organize my code as I currently have a very large line chart with the same 'var options' but with a lot more attributes.

Comment: Those are options used by Google Charts to customize your chart. No need to convert anything, just define those var options prior to draw()'ing and you'll be set. Keep it in the same .js file and include that on your webpage.

Comment: @yjzhou you can have multiple javascript files. You can either use modules or just load scripts in html

Comment: @Konrad - thank you for the advice, I will use modules to clean up my code. Do you have advice for how to split up my code? for example, separate functions, classes and variables? Or should I separate based off of how they relate to each other?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan In fairness, that comment may be a good answer to this question.